# ImageSharp draw image on image in Vb.net

Tags: c#, vb.net, imagesharp

I'm trying to build a sprite image on a VB.Net Standard class with SixLabors ImageSharp.
I know how to code it on C#, but Vb.Net does not seem to accept a blank Image constructor with width and height and complain with a messsage I don't fully understand.

C# constructor:

```
using (Image<Rgba32> outputImage = new Image<Rgba32>(width, height)) {
...
}
```

Vb.Net failed constructor:

```
Using outputImage As New Image(Of Rgba32)(width, height)
...
End Using
```

Warning message:

> Type argument 'Rgba32' does not inherit from or implement the constant. Type '?' '' is an unsupported type

Intellisense is asking for Image(Of TPixel as {Structure,,ipixel(Of TPixel)}), which I don't see how to write in the constructor

Comment: had a little look into this apparently, with the current api it is not possible to new up a `Image<TPixel>` because the `TPixel` has the `unmanaged` constraint and VB.NET has no plans on supporting it (https://github.com/dotnet/vblang/issues/300). I have created a ticket in the ImageSharp repo to track this issue https://github.com/SixLabors/ImageSharp/issues/1202